# N^2 and two counter machines

Tags: nt.number-theory, computability-theory

I asked this [question on cstheory a few months ago](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19551/can-a-two-counters-machine-decide-n2), but I didn't receive an answer, so I'm posting it here to see if there are original ideas from the "math world" to solve it. The original question asks about recognizing the language $L = \{N^2 \mid N \geq 1\}$ on a two counter machine, but I'll give here an equivalent formulation.

Suppose that you can write a program on a machine equipped with a single integer register $R$ and the following instruction set:

- **Add $K$** : adds a constant $K \geq 0$ to the register;
- **Mul $K$** : multiplies the register by $K \geq 0$;
- **DJZ $lab$** : subtract one from the register, if the result is zero jump to label $lab$; otherwise continue with the next instruction;
- **Div $K, lab_0$,$lab_1$,...,$lab_{K-1}$** : divide the register by $K>0$, and place the quotient in the register (R = R div K); then jump to one of the $K$ labels according to the remainder (R mod K); the labels are not necessarily distinct;
- **Jump $lab$** : unconditional jump to label $lab$
- **Halt (ACCEPT|REJECT)** : stop the computation and ACCEPT or REJECT

Every instruction can have a label.

The question is:

> If the register $R$ is initially loaded with an integer $M \geq 1$, can we build a program that ACCEPTs if and only if $M$ is a square (i.e. $M = N^2$)?

The problem originally appeared in:

[Rich Schroeppel, "A Two counter Machine Cannot Calculate $2^N$" [1972]](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/6202/AIM-257.pdf?sequence=2)

(and perhaps has been solved, but I didn't find anything).

Note: in Schroeppel's paper the above model is called *More Powerful One Register Machine* (MP1RM) and is equivalent to a 2 counter machine.

Comment: It looks to me like in the question on cstheory there are two registers whereas here I see only one.  What am I missing?

Comment: It appears to me the problem is equivalent to the following: is there a constant $c>0$ and a unary integer function $f$ definable in Presburger arithmetic such that for every $n$, the iterates $f^{(k)}(cn)$ eventually stabilize in a fixpoint, and $n$ is a square iff the fixpoint is (say) $0$.

Comment: @NoahStein: The two formulations are equivalent (see Schroeppel's paper), the one I gave here is called More Powerful 1 Register  Machine (MP1RM). In the 2 counter version there are no div/mul operations.

Comment: The only paper at MathSciNet that references Schroeppel's paper is MR2440596 (2009e:03073); 
Dershowitz, Nachum; Gurevich, Yuri; 
A natural axiomatization of computability and proof of Church's Thesis.  
Bull. Symbolic Logic 14 (2008), no. 3, 299–350.

Comment: I didn't mean to express or imply any opinion on whether the problem is still open; I just hoped I could save people the effort of checking something on MathSciNet. It might be worth looking at the Dershowitz-Gurevich paper to see whether they had anything to say about the question, if you haven't already done that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: ok, thanks. After a quick look, it seems that there are no releveant correlations; but the paper seems very interesting on its own! (I'll surely read it more carefully :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved in:

Oscar H. Ibarra, Nicholas Q. Trân, A note on simple programs with two variables, Theoretical Computer Science, Volume 112, Issue 2, 10 May 1993, Pages 391-397, ISSN 0304-3975, [http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(93)90028-R](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975%2893%2990028-R).

Let $TV$ be the class of languages recognized by two-counter machines.

> **Theorem 3.3**: For any fixed integer $k \geq 2$, $L_k = \{ n^k \mid n \geq 0 \} \notin TV$